# Could Laplace's Demon be the universe itself?

Tags: metaphysics, determinism

Laplace proposed that a being that could know the state of the universe at one particular point in time and knowing all the laws governing that universe would be able to determine the past and future events from that state.

Rather than that Demon to be a being or a machine within that universe, could that Demon be the universe itself?

Comment: In that case, maybe the Demon will be God itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laplace's idea is basically that the universe is deterministic and governed by classical mechanics. So essentially nothing but atoms (small balls) flying around and bumping into each other. So if you knew the location and momentum of every atom in the universe you could map out the trajectory of every such particle. And if the universe is just the set of all these particles one could thus calculate the past, present or future state of the universe itself.

However if you want to describe N particles, each of which having momentum and location, you've effectively 2N properties to account for. So you have more variables to deal with than you'd have particles in your universe. Meaning you'd need something "supernatural", that is something that operates OUTSIDE of that universe where they aren't limited by the constraints of that universe hence the "demon".

The other problem of the in-universe observer is that he/she/it would be PART OF THAT UNIVERSE. Meaning their calculations would need to account for themselves and their calculation as well. And not only that, but because they happen inside the universe they also either need to be deterministically governed by classical mechanics in which case you're not really able to account for everything everywhere in one place or the observer would be able to act with free will and just observe, in which case they'd disturb the universe and make their calculation wrong or you know they need to be placed outside of it.

With regards to your question, well the universe is able to predict its future (via the progression of time), but is it able to compute the past and present? That's like saying a falling apple knows the trajectory of it's fall. It's true but kinda cheating as there's no calculation happening that you could look at outside of experiencing the even as it happens. Though maybe the calculation would be so complex that in effect it would be a simulation of the very event...

Comment: Do our minds reason or calculate?

Comment: "... the universe is able to predict it's future" Whenever there is time, the universe *has* future, for sure (or do you mean "its" instead of "it's" [ = it has]?)

Comment: Doesn't the last paragraph (the universe is able to predict it's future) contradict the second paragraph (predicting the universe needs more resource than the universe has)?

Comment: @8Mad0Manc8 Both, though in that case we'd have (theoretically) an open information game so "all we'd need to do" is calculate.

Comment: @rexkogitans Yes I mean its, need to edit that later.

Comment: @kutschkem It's similar to how you can't time travel unless you think about moving forward in time in infinitely small quantities ... Like you'd do if you don't time travel but just live. Also that would only work in the forward direction and only for the next moment not the distant future or past etc.

Answer (score 5):

The demon must be an outside observer of the deterministic universe.

The universe is calculating its future states as fast as physically possible. The demon possesses complete knowledge of the universe, infinite computing power and the free will to initiate calculations. None of this is possible *within* a deterministic universe.

Comment: An operator of the machine?